# Finite difference/Euler method for system of ODE IVP in Fortran 90/95?

Tags: fortran, ode

I think there might be similar question asked (I didn't find any though). Is there any Fortran 90/95 code to solve coupled ODEs IVP using finite difference or Euler method (I do believe it is available, I didn't find though)? I have about 150 coupled ODEs with IVP of following form,

```
dx1(t)/dt=a01+a11.x2(t)+a12.x3(t)-b11.x1(t)
dx2(t)/dt=a02+a22.x3(t)-b22.x2(t)
dx3(t)/dt=a03+a31.x1(t)+a32.x2(t)-b13.x3(t)
```

where a's and b's are constants, t is time,

```
x1(t=0)=0,x2(t=0)=0,x3(t=0)=0
```

Comment: Do note that questions asking for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here, in case you are not clear on this refer to the help centre where it is all explained.  And asking where you should ask this sort of question would also be off-topic.

Comment: Do you need Euler or does any solver do like rk4, rk45/dopri, rkf45,...?

Comment: As @HighPerformanceMark mentions, the policy of stackoverflow is to disallow questions such as "advising for which software to pick". There are plenty of Fortran libraries for scientific computing, including for solving ODEs, you have probably not asked google "Fortran ordinary differential equation".

Comment: I need either Euler or finite difference method. Thanks. I "ll do it using library..

Comment: The Euler's method is a method for solving ODE's. It is so trivial there there is almost nothing to program. You will find libraries mostly for Runge-Kutta methods instead.  The term finite-difference is a broad term for many various methods, there is not *the finite difference method*. Also, this term is normally used in the context of PDE's, not ODE's. I suggest to learn more about the mathematics of this.  Then you will see the explicit Euler method is completely trivial to program.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks. I am going through mathematics...